# What are some examples of journals that will accept undergraduate student research?

Tags: soft-question, gr.group-theory, journals

I am currently doing a research project with a professor and 3 other students in an area that is usually seen as a "recreational" math topic; that of change-ringing and its relation to group theory. The papers regarding change-ringing that I have managed to find on JSTOR are generally of an expository nature, and since we do have one or two somewhat original results (we were trying to see what subgroups of Sn can be enumerated using transformations allowed under the restrictions of change-ringing), I think we might have something at least worth trying to submit to a small journal.

Does anyone have any recommendations?

Comment: Offhand, it seems most appropriate to raise this with the professor first.

Comment: For those, like me, who have no idea what change ringing means: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change_ringing#Permuting_the_bells 
$$ $$ 
I'm tempted to say that your professor may have a better idea (knowing what kind of results that you've proven) than Joe Mathematician can provide in regards to your question. 

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of http://mathoverflow.net/questions/36850/journals-for-undergraduates to me

Comment: Au contraire, Alex, that other question is about journals suitable for undergraduates *to read*, not to publish in. 

Comment: (But of course, some of the suggestions in that thread will also be appropriate to this question.)

Comment: The AKS primality test was published in Annals; two of the authors performed their work on this while undergraduates.

Comment: No journal I know of cares a hoot about what degrees the authors have or don't have. It's only the work that counts. On other hand, if it's joint work, the discussion should definitely start among the collaborators first. And, for better or worse, the senior member of the team probably has the most say on what happens. I would have reacted better to this question if it had been made clear that the collaborators had already discussed this before posting the question on MO.

Comment: @deane-yang, I agree with you. They jumped the gun.  In my answer below, I didn't point out the impropriety of jumping a step ahead of your collaborators in deciding where/when to publish, but asking the senior-most person on the team does seem to be the best course of action.  And if the collaborators **had** discussed this with someone who has published before (as their professor most certainly has), then they would not even have had a question to submit here, as they'd already have an answer.

Comment: Thank you for your comments regarding propriety - as an undergraduate, I am not fully aware of all the social norms regarding collaboration and publishing. I certainly did not intend to side-step any members of the team. The purpose of my question, which likely was not clear, was to gauge whether or not there are journals even open to this sort of thing, since although there are *specifically* undergraduate conferences aplenty, I was unsure whether the same sort of forum existed in journal form.

Comment: @SAC, I didn't mean in any way to offend, or claim that you were out of line. Your desire to publish (even if you haven't discussed it with others'at home'yet) shows initiative* and indicates that you'll go somewhere in life, as long as you've got a follow-through to go along with the ambition and desire. You asked a good question; you should definitely discuss it with your advisor/mentor. Even though there may be journals that cater specifically to undergraduate research, my point below is still valid. If you've got real results, publish in the appropriate forum for the topic. Best wishes :)

Answer (score 18):

Permit me to draw attention to the journal,
[Involve—A Journal of Mathematics](http://pjm.math.berkeley.edu/involve/about/cover/cover.html)
(which I also mentioned in [a related MO posting](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/25421/how-do-undergrad-students-write-papers-by-themselves/28331#28331)). Snippets from *About the Journal*:

> "*Involve* is dedicated to showcasing and encouraging high quality mathematical research involving students (at all levels). ... Submissions in all mathematical areas are encouraged. However, each manuscript should include a minimum of 1/3 student authorship. ...
>   Involve is a publication in between the extremes of purely undergraduate research journals, which in general are aimed at undergraduate audiences, and mainstream research journals."

The current issue is its 10th.

Comment: Although there are a few other journals that routinely publish student work, *Involve* is the only journal I know that is explicitly dedicated to showcasing students efforts (undergraduates or graduates). This is a very commendable goal that deserves our support. 

Comment: Thanks so much! It looks like a really interesting endeavor.

Comment: There's also the Canadian journal Crux Mathematicorum (http://math.ca/crux/).  Though it is a problem solving journal, they do regularly publish short articles.  With an audience primarily of undergraduate and secondary school students, your results might be a bit too advanced (I suspect group theory is too advanced -- number theory is probably better received, or "pure" combinatorics), but others with similar questions might find them a better fit.

Comment: Out of curiosity, does a publication in Involve (or a journal similar to it) help for PhD admissions?

Comment: @Anonymous: Yes, certainly. Any publication helps, for it demonstrates research experience.

Answer (score 3):

Electronic Journal of Combinatorics might be a good candidate considering the topic.  My contention is that if the paper has a real result which is mathematical and combinatoric in nature, and is well-written, then the education-level of the author(s) should not play a role in whether the paper is appropriate or not for a particular journal.

Whether or not one or more of the authors is an undergraduate still working on their studies or already holds a Ph.D. or teaching position should not be a factor.  However, the best person to tell you about the most appropriate forum in which to attempt to publish your findings is **your mentor**, the professor sponsoring or advising you as you do this research.  It is your advisor's job to advise about something like this, and they will have the best and most appropriate answer for you.  People who don't know the details of your work, as the rest of these readers/commentators on Mathoverflow and slashdot are, cannot give you an informed answer.  You should look closer to home, and ask your teachers and your undergraduate advisors, or an appropriate mathematician in your local mathematics department.

Answer (score 3):

I haven't seen mentioned the [AMS undergraduate mathematics page](http://www.ams.org/programs/students/undergrad/undergrad), in particular the "Clubs, Conferences, Events, Online Journals" section. The section mentions the following journals targeting undergraduates:

- [Involve](http://www.involvemath.org/), mentioned in another answer.
- [The Rose-Hulman Institute of Technology Undergraduate Mathematics Journal](http://www.rose-hulman.edu/mathjournal/index.php), which requires an established mathematician to sponsor your submission and recommend referees.
- [The Harvard College Mathematics Review](http://www.thehcmr.org/), focuses on expository articles by undergraduates. It also sadly seems to be semi-defunct, the website promises an issue in March but one has not yet appeared.

There is also a new undergraduate journal [The Waterloo Mathematics Review](http://mathreview.uwaterloo.ca/) from the University of Waterloo (full disclosure: I am one of the editors) in a similar style to the HCMR, though it also accepts original research. We are currently accepting submissions for our second issue, while this answer may find you too late I hope you consider submitting.

Comment: The HCMR was defunct for a year or so but I was told they were back up and running again. Huh. 

Comment: Thank you! Question: the website for the Waterloo Review says that the submissions are from "undergraduates across Canada" - does that still allow for work from elsewhere in North America?

Comment: There is a similar page hosted by the University of Nebraska that lists [undergraduate research journals in math and physics](https://unl.libguides.com/c.php?g=51642&p=333916).

Answer (score 2):

You might first want to read the article by Arthur White & Robin Wilson: "The hunting group", *The Mathematical Gazette* **79**, no. 484, March 1995, which is about the group theory of change ringing.

Comment: A later, web-accessible, article with many references (though not this one) is http://math.lib.umn.edu/changeringing.html

Comment: Indeed! I've really enjoyed looking at White's "ethnomathematical" works, since they deftly combine the history of change-ringing, which was developed before Galois and Abel introduced any modern group-theoretical concepts, with sketches of proofs concerning the "ringability" of certain groups. In this project, we've made a small amount of headway into looking at groups that White doesn't cover, such as the alternating group.